# How would I go about decompiling an exe that only will run on windows XP

Tags: exe, decompiling

I started as an intern recently for a science research lab. My boss wants to port a software she uses on a windows XP computer. The only info I have is a basic overview of what it does and some exe files. That’s it. I don’t have the equations it runs either. My boss believes it was written in basic or fortran. The original author lost all the source code and doesn’t want I’m clueless with decompiling and was wondering how I should get started. Thanks!

Comment: Port in which sense? Can!t you just run the software on the new computer? Good luck with interpretting the machine code, that is not task for an intern but for a good team that know what they are doing and received necessary details. Basic and Fortran are both completely different and irrelevant for this question, hence I will remove the tags.

Comment: Getting the assembly code from an exe is easy, tell is your details if you can!t even do that. But I doubt the assembly code will be of much use for you.

Comment: Port to which system? If it's newer Windows, then maybe it would run with some extra settings. If it's some other OS family, decompiling and reconstituting something seems like a hopeless quest. I'd make a Win XP VM and run it in that...

Comment: this is open source and free try this if it doesn't work just google decompiler windows xp https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Debuggers-Decompilers-Dissasemblers/Decompiler.shtml